# PHP filtering results based on data

Tags: php, sql, select

I'm trying to filter some query results with a 'select' system. But I'm having zero success...

Here is the select code:

```
echo "<select name='period'>";
echo "<option value='select-period'>Select a period</option>";
echo "<option value='today'>Today</option>";
echo "<option value='7 days'>Last 7 days</option>";
echo "<option value='30 days'>Last month</option>";
echo "<option value='365 days'>Last year</option>";
echo "</select>";
```

Here is the query code:

```
$sqlCidade = "SELECT count( * ) FROM $table_name WHERE form_value REGEXP '.*\"city\";s:[0-9]+:\"$valorCidade\".'";
```

Everything works perfectly. But I need to filter the results based on the select options. I tried with an

```
AND form_date > current_date - interval '7 days'
```

at the end, but it didn't worked.

(`form_date` is the column on the db that has the posting date)

Comment: define "didn't work". You get an error? Or just unexpected results? It looks to me like your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You don't show how the data gets from the form to the SQL, and we don't know what your source data is to know whether the output would be correct. So really we need a bit more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can use **DATE_SUB()** Mysql function check this [func_mysql_date_sub](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_sub.asp)

And try like this

```
echo "<select name='period'>";
echo "<option value='select-period'>Select a period</option>";
echo "<option value='1 DAY'>Today</option>";
echo "<option value='7 DAY'>Last 7 days</option>";
echo "<option value='30 DAY'>Last month</option>";
echo "<option value='365 DAY'>Last year</option>";
echo "</select>";

AND form_date >DATE_SUB(current_date, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```